# How to split server.xml of apache tomcat into several separate files?

Tags: tomcat, config, virtualhost, server.xml

I use apache tomcat 7 to run a lot ofo virtual hosts on a single machine, I insert a `Host` tag for every virtual host in server.xml, so I can manage them in a centralized manner.
But now, after adding a lot of host tags, server.xml became so large & I'm seeking for a way to put every virtual host related tags in a separated xml file (exactly same that apache does for httpd.conf & virtual host management). e.g I make a separate xml file for every host & put all of them into a directory & force tomcat to load them!
Any Idea???

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following should work but doesn't due to a Tomcat bug. I've fixed the bug in trunk ([r1333827](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc?view=revision&revision=1333827)) and 7.0.x ([r1333829](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc?view=revision&revision=1333829)) and the fix will be included in Tomcat 7.0.28 onwards. I could have sworn that this worked previously. It may be that the xml parser in the JVM has been tightened up at some point and that this will still work with older JVM versions but I haven't tested that.

You can use XML entities - one for each host. For example:

Insert the following just before the `<server>` element:

```
<!DOCTYPE server-xml [
  <!ENTITY host1 SYSTEM "host1.txt">
]>
```

The contents of host1.txt is the host element you want to define:

```
<Host>
  ...
</Host>
```

And then you insert this into server.xml inside the `<engine>` element like this:

```
<engine ...>
  &host1;
</engine>
```

Repeat for as many hosts as you need.

Comment: Thanks, this solution works fine, but is there anyway that we don't need to change server.xml to add any extra command when we add new host? something like using <!ENTITY all_hosts SYSTEM "*.txt">

Comment: How would I specify an absolute path to the xml file I want to include?

Comment: Just specifying an absolute path doesn't work (/my/absolute/path/file.txt)?

Comment: Does the extra server file need to end with ".txt" or can it end with "xml"? Example <!ENTITY foobar SYSTEM "foobar-server.xml">

Comment: Can an host1.txt have its own  <!ENTITY > tags to include additonal files? Such as you can include hosts.txt from server.xml which includes all the other host.

Comment: Is there still no option to use a wildcard to specify all files rather than specifying each file?

Comment: @ Ehsan Khodarahmi, were you able to find a solution to enter all host entries using a wildcard entry